# Websocket connection in Kubernetes cluster with nginx-ingress

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to get a simple websocket connection working on my server running in a Kubernetes cluster.

Websocket connections are able to establish on my local test machine but I can't connect my client side to the server after I deploy to GKE with nginx-ingress.

ingress yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.org/websocket-services : "socket-cluster-ip-service"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services : "socket-cluster-ip-service"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-socket.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: socket-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3000
    - host: www.my-socket.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: socket-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3000
```

service yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: socket-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: socket
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```

deployment yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: socket-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: socket
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: socket
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: socket
        image: gcr.io/my-socket/socket
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

express server code:

```
...

var server = http.createServer(app);
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server: server });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  console.log("new connection", ws)
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});

...
```

client side code:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.my-socket.com/');

ws.onopen = () => {
  // connection opened
  ws.send('something'); // send a message
};

ws.onmessage = (e) => {
  // a message was received
  console.log(e.data);
};

ws.onerror = (e) => {
  // an error occurred
  console.log(e.message);
};

ws.onclose = (e) => {
  // connection closed
  console.log(e.code, e.reason);
};
```

I keep getting the error message "Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response" from the client side. But I think it's just the fact that the client could not establish websocket connection with the server.

The server side library I used is [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws)

I've added the following annotations to my ingress yaml file as suggested by [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770981/using-socket-io-on-gke-with-nginx-ingress) and [official ingress-nginx documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/#websockets) but it's still not working:

```
nginx.org/websocket-services : "socket-cluster-ip-service"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services : "socket-cluster-ip-service"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it works like a charm!
I'm using
**kong-docker-kubernetes-ingress-controller.bintray.io/kong-ingress-controller:0.9.0**
on my private kubernetes cluster.
Thus, your issue might be related to GCE.

Please also check your TLS configuration.
In your post you were mentioning `ws://...` rather than `wss://`, which indicates you don't even use TLS. This might be rejected by your browser (e.g. Chrome).

Comment: @ Christian Arnheiter, i am facing same issue, in my local, able to establish web socket connection from client (angular ng2-stompjs) to server (spring boot). But when i deploy client and server applications on k8s cluster, i see "java.io.IOException: Unable to unwrap data, invalid status [CLOSED]" error after protocol switch is success (Completed 101 SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS). We are using Kong Ingress Controller v0.9.1, do we need to set any proxy configurations at ingress level?

Answer (score 0):

im not on GKE however this might help the above issue:
https://medium.com/k8scaleio/running-websocket-app-on-kubernetes-2e13eabb4c4f

it's to do with persistent state.
I'm having the same issue works perfectly, when i run the docker image locally(docker run...) but the image deployed inside the cluster (k3d with loadbalacncer exposing its port )...web-socket will not connect.
other services exposed (rest->mysql etc all work fine only the nodejs app with web-socket fails)

solution is to add annotations to your ingress controller rules:

annotations section in the yaml file:

```
certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: [your issuer]
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: ws-service
nginx.org/websocket-services: ws-service
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).